# Manipulating counter information - Python 2.7

Tags: python, collections, counter

I'm fairly new to Python and I have this program that I was tinkering with. It's supposed to get a string from input and display which character is the most frequent.

```
stringToData = raw_input("Please enter your string: ")
    # imports collections class
import collections
    # gets the data needed from the collection
letter, count = collections.Counter(stringToData).most_common(1)[0]
    # prints the results
print "The most frequent character is %s, which occurred %d times." % (
letter, count)
```

However, if the string has 1 of each character, it only displays one letter and says it's the most frequent character. I thought about changing the number in the parenthesis in most_common(number), but I didn't want more to display how many times the other letters every time.

Thank you to all that help!

Comment: You can leave off the parameter to `most_common` to get a list of all characters, ordered from most common to least common. Then just loop through that result and collect the characters as long as the counter value is still the same. That way you get all characters that are most common.

Comment: So leave off the (1) on most_common? How would I access that list now, by using most_common()?

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in the comment:

> You can leave off the parameter to `most_common` to get a list of all characters, ordered from most common to least common. Then just loop through that result and collect the characters as long as the counter value is still the same. That way you get all characters that are most common.

[`Counter.most_common(n)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) returns the `n` most common elements from the counter. Or in case where `n` is not specified, it will return all elements from the counter, ordered by the count.

```
>>> collections.Counter('abcdab').most_common()
[('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 1), ('d', 1)]
```

You can use this behavior to simply loop through all elements, ordered by their count. As long as the count is the same as of the first element in the output, you know that the element still ocurred in the same quantity in the string.

```
>>> c = collections.Counter('abcdefgabc')
>>> maxCount = c.most_common(1)[0][1]

>>> elements = []
>>> for element, count in c.most_common():
        if count != maxCount:
            break
        elements.append(element)
>>> elements
['a', 'c', 'b']

>>> [e for e, c in c.most_common() if c == maxCount]
['a', 'c', 'b']
```